# How to get the event source in kendo ui, when several objects share the same view model?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have the following minimal repro code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="popup" >
  <form id="popup-editor-form">
      <div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content" style="overflow:visible;">
          <div class="k-edit-form-container">
              <div class="k-edit-field">
                <a href="" data-bind="click:addProducts">Add Additional Products + </a>
              </div>
              <div id="additionalProducts"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
</div>


<script>  
  var editWindow = $("#popup").kendoWindow({
      modal: true,
      visible: false,
      resizable: false,
  });

  var viewModel = {};
  viewModel.count = 0;
  viewModel.dropdownChange = function(e) {
    // I need to get the dropdown id that just have been changed here 
    alert('hello');
  }
  viewModel.source = [{Name:"Apples",productValue:"app"},{Name:"Oranges",productValue:"or"}];
  viewModel.addProducts = function() {
    var dropdownMarkup = '<div class="k-edit-label">'+
                    '<label>Product</label>'+
                '</div>'+

                '<div class="k-edit-field">' +
                    '<input name="Product Type' + viewModel.count + '" id="type' + viewModel.count + '"' +
                        'data-role="dropdownlist"' +
                        'data-auto-bind="true"' +
                        'data-value-primitive="true"' +
                        'data-option-label="<No product selected>"' +
                        'data-text-field="Name"' +
                        'data-value-field="productValue"' +
                        'data-text="Select Product..."' +
                        'data-bind="value: productValue'+ viewModel.count + ',' +
                        'source: source,' +
                        'events: { change: dropdownChange}" />' +
                '</div>';
    $('#additionalProducts').append(dropdownMarkup);
    kendo.bind(editWindow, viewModel);
    viewModel.count++;
    return false;
  }

  kendo.bind(editWindow, viewModel);  
  editWindow.data("kendoWindow").title("MyWindow");
  editWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

A user can add several products. When they do, a new dropdown with the product selection is created. `dropdownChange` event is fired when the user select something in a dropdown.

However I can't figure out which dropdown the event has originated from. The event parameter does not contain anything useful, and `this` points to the viewmodel, which is the same for all the dropdowns.

Ideally I want to be able to receive id of the dropdown that has just changed - I will need to add additional fields next to this specific dropdown based on which product from the list was selected.

How do I found which dropdown was changed inside 'dropdownChange'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which information you need from the original `input` but `e.sender` is the KendoUI DropDown object and `e.sender.element[0]` is the `input` element.

In the following snippet I've modified your code for displaying the `input` `name`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var editWindow = $("#popup").kendoWindow({
    modal: true,
    visible: false,
    resizable: false,
  });

  var viewModel = {};
  viewModel.count = 0;
  viewModel.dropdownChange = function(e) {
    // I need to get the dropdown id that just have been changed here 
    alert('hello:' + e.sender.element[0].name);
  }
  viewModel.source = [{Name:"Apples",productValue:"app"},{Name:"Oranges",productValue:"or"}];
  viewModel.addProducts = function() {
    var dropdownMarkup = '<div class="k-edit-label">'+
        '<label>Product</label>'+
        '</div>'+

        '<div class="k-edit-field">' +
        '<input name="Product Type' + viewModel.count + '" id="type' + viewModel.count + '"' +
        'data-role="dropdownlist"' +
        'data-auto-bind="true"' +
        'data-value-primitive="true"' +
        'data-option-label="<No product selected>"' +
        'data-text-field="Name"' +
        'data-value-field="productValue"' +
        'data-text="Select Product..."' +
        'data-bind="value: productValue'+ viewModel.count + ',' +
        'source: source,' +
        'events: { change: dropdownChange}" />' +
        '</div>';
    $('#additionalProducts').append(dropdownMarkup);
    kendo.bind(editWindow, viewModel);
    viewModel.count++;
    return false;
  }

  kendo.bind(editWindow, viewModel);  
  editWindow.data("kendoWindow").title("MyWindow");
  editWindow.data("kendoWindow").center().open();

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.3.1316/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="popup" >
  <form id="popup-editor-form">
    <div class="k-popup-edit-form k-window-content k-content" style="overflow:visible;">
      <div class="k-edit-form-container">
        <div class="k-edit-field">
          <a href="" data-bind="click:addProducts">Add Additional Products + </a>
        </div>
        <div id="additionalProducts"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```